# Transforming node contents to remove whitespace

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

If the contents of a `citations` node is something like the following:

```
                <p>

            WAJWAJADS:

            </p>

<p>

            asdf

            </p>

<p>

            ALSOAS:

            </p>

<p>

            lorem ipsum...<br />
lorem<br />
blah blah <i>

            adfas &amp; dasdsaafs

            </i>, April 2011.<br />
lorem lorem dear lord the whitespace

            </p>
```

Is there any way to transform this to properly formatted HTML with XSLT?

`normalize-space()` just concats everything together. The best I've managed to do is `normalize-space()` on all `p` descendants within a `for-each` loop and wrap them in a `p` element. However, then any inner tags are still lost.

Is there a better way to parse this WYSIWYG generated trainwreck? Unfortunately I have no control over the generated XML.

Comment: What is your definition of "properly formatted HTML"?

Comment: No additional whitespace between node start/end and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've modified a little the answer by Martin Honnen:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:if test="substring(., string-length(.)) = ' ' and substring(., string-length(.) - 1, string-length(.)) != '  '">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

it tests if the last character is a space and the last 2 characters are not both spaces, if true, it inserts a space.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to have a well-formed XML with a root.

Assuming you have that, you can apply an *identity transform* to copy the source tree to the result, *strip spaces* between the tags, optionally generate output in HTML (without the XML declaration) and indented, and use `normalize-space()` only in the text nodes.

Try this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result applied to the data you provided will be:

```
<p>WAJWAJADS:</p>
<p>asdf</p>
<p>ALSOAS:</p>
<p>lorem ipsum...<br>lorem<br>blah blah<i>adfas &amp; dasdsaafs</i>, April 2011.<br>lorem lorem dear lord the whitespace
</p>
```

You can see the result applied to your example in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsE)**

**UPDATE 1**: to add an extra space around each text node (and avoid concatenation when the string value of the node is calculated) you can replace the last template with:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',normalize-space(.),' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<html>
   <p> WAJWAJADS: </p>
   <p> asdf </p>
   <p> ALSOAS: </p>
   <p> lorem ipsum... <br> lorem <br> blah blah <i> adfas &amp; dasdsaafs </i> , April 2011. <br> lorem lorem dear lord the whitespace 
   </p>
</html>
```

See: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsE/1

**UPDATE 2**:  to add a space or newline *after* each copied *element*. Place this `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` (for a newline) or this `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` (for a space) after the `</xsl:copy>` in the *first* template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<html>
   <p>WAJWAJADS:</p>

   <p>asdf</p>

   <p>ALSOAS:</p>

   <p>lorem ipsum...<br>
      lorem<br>
      blah blah<i>adfas &amp; dasdsaafs</i>
      , April 2011.<br>
      lorem lorem dear lord the whitespace
   </p>

</html>
```

See: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsE/2

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of `@*|node()` in your answer?

Comment: The `@` is the same as `attribute::`, which means the attribute axis. `@*` or `attribute::*` means *any* attribute. `node()` matches *any* node except attributes and namespaces (it matches elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions). The `|` is the union operator. The final expression matches attributes or any text, comment, processing instruction or element.

Comment: The `<xsl:copy>` simply copies the matched node. The `<xsl:apply-templates/>` inside `<xsl:copy>` has to be explicitly set to select attributes as well, since the default is to not select them.

Comment: As you can see in your fiddle the problem is with the inner elements such as `i`. Because of `normalize-space()` the text contents of these elements are mashed together with the parent text.

Comment: That can be compensated adding a space before and after each text node: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',normalize-space(.),' ')"/>`. See: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsE/1

Comment: Or by adding a space or newline after each copied element. Place this `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` after the `</xsl:copy>` in the first template. See: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsE/2

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation template plus a template for text nodes doing the normalize-space:

`<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0):

This question would have been a lot easier to understand if the example contained real text instead of gibberish. "*No additional whitespace between node start/end and text.*" is not an accurate enough description of the expected result.

I am going to take a guess here and assume you actually want to perform a "**run of spaces to one space**" operation on all the text nodes. This could be done as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="normalize-space(concat('x', ., 'x'))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($temp, 2, string-length($temp) - 2)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following test input:

```
<chapter>


           <p>

    This         question          would         have

been       a     lot    <b>   easier      </b>      to understand 

        if     the      example   contained     

   <i>     real  </i>    text    instead   of 

   gibberish.

                     </p>


    <p>

    Here     is       an      example       of     preserving   zero     spaces 

    between    text   nodes:<br/>(continued)       on   a new   line. 




    </p>


        <p>

    Here  is       another      example       of     

    preserving   zero     spaces     within    a      text

    node:     <i>some     text  in      italic</i>       followed    

    by   normal      text. 


    </p>


</chapter>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
   <p> This question would have been a lot <b> easier </b> to understand if the example contained <i> real </i> text instead of gibberish. </p>
   <p> Here is an example of preserving zero spaces between text nodes:<br/>(continued) on a new line. </p>
   <p> Here is another example of preserving zero spaces within a text node: <i>some text in italic</i> followed by normal text. </p>
</chapter>
```

--
Note that there will be no difference between the input and output when rendered in HTML.